# What is this theorem about measurable functions saying?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

**Theorem:**

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ be a measurable space and let $f:\Omega \rightarrow Y$ be a given function. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a collection of subsets of $Y$.

If $f^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal{F}$ for every $A \in \mathcal{A}$, then $f^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal{F}$ for every $A \in \sigma(\mathcal{A})$.

**Questions**:

I understand that $\Omega$ is the underlying set and $\mathcal{F}$ is a class of subsets of $\Omega$ that is closed under finite unions and complementation (i.e., $\mathcal{F}$ is a field). But what is $Y$? And what is the purpose of defining $\mathcal{A}$ as a *collection of subsets* of $Y$, with $A$ an element in that collection? Moreover, what is the message of the theorem?

The notation is throwing me off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Y$ is defined in $f:\Omega\to Y$ (it is a space, containing the image of $f$).

$\mathcal{A}$ is a family of subsets of $Y$, not necessarily a $\sigma$-algebra. The point of the theorem is exactly to say that it is sufficient to check the measurability of $f$ for family of sets generating the $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$, instead of the whole $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$ (e.g. if $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ is the $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$, then it is sufficient to check the measurability for all elements $A\in \mathcal{A}$ instead of all elements $A\in\sigma(\mathcal{A})$).